# Django getting ForeignKey objects in APIView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hey so I am new to Django and I am writing a REST API with the following model .

```
# models.py
class Order(models.Model):
    order_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.order_name).


class LineItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'product')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.order.order_name, self.product.product_name).


# views.py
class OrderList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        orderlist = Order.objects.all()
        serializer = OrderSerializer(orderlist, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class OrderDetail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, order):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, order_name):
        snippet = Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        snippet = snippet.lineitem_set.all()
        serializer = OrderSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So I am trying to code the OrderDetail(APIView)'s get method so that at /api/order/OrderA/ I get JSON with all the lineitems in that order. I've been struggling for a while with this now. Any suggestions?

`class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_name']`

Comment: can you add **`OrderSerializer`** class to the question?

Comment: done. This is what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your serializer as below,

```
class LineItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields = ('id', 'product')
        depth = 1


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    line_items = LineItemSerializer(many=True, source='lineitem_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['order_name', 'line_items']
```

and then in your **`OrderDetail`** view as

```
class OrderDetail(APIView):
    # your code

    def get(self, request, order_name):
        snippet = Order.objects.get(order_name=order_name)
        serializer = OrderSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This did work. Thanks so much. But I have another question. Is it possible to get fieldnames back instead of field ids? That would make the model be much better. It is kind of important as well to get product_name in response

Comment: @NavrajSinghChhina add **`depth=1`** in `LineItemSerializer`. Updated  the answer

Comment: @NavrajSinghChhina You should mark the answer if solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

DRF gives you a class to get the details of an object. Have a look here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview

This an example code that should work if the `order_name` is passed as param in the url using a GET method.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

# the decorator avoid to cache the object, maybe you don't need that.
@method_decorator(never_cache, name="dispatch")
class OrderDetail(RetrieveAPIView):

    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Order.objects.get(order_name=self.kwargs.get('order_name'))
        except Order.DoesNotExist:
            raise NotFound()
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question, this thing just returns the Order_name only. I need to get all the fields in LineItem with order_name=order_name.